# Where is the Dark Brotherhood?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Oblivion some of my favorite quests were the Dark Brotherhood quest line. Where can I start the dark brotherhood quest line a in Skyrim?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Head to Rorikstead and ask the inn keeper about rumors. He'll inform you about a kid. (The kid is Aventus Aretino in Windhelm, if you want to skip the rumor gathering) This will start the [dark brotherhood](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dark_Brotherhood) questline.

Comment: by mistake i went to aretino and killd this old woman. and now i dont think i can begin the darkbrotherhood quest. any ideas?

Comment: If you went to Aretino and killed Grelod the Kind, then you _have_ started the Dark Brotherhood questline.  Just wait a couple days and they'll... contact you...

Comment: Don't just *wait*, the Dark Brotherhood will 'recruit' you for your work with Grelod after you *sleep*. They work fast, too. Only needs to be a quick 1 hour nap in any bed.

Answer (score 1):

Another option to start the Dark Brotherhood questline can be found in Riften. Head to the Honorhall Orphanage and listen to the horrible, disgusting woman who runs it as she belittles and verbally abuses the children inside. Upon viewing this small conversation, you can then speak to one of the children in the orphanage. They will tell you about Aventus Aretino, and ask you to find him. This also begins the Dark Brotherhood quest.